# show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1}{{n}\choose{i}}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have to show that

a)  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1}{{n}\choose{i}}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1}$

edit:

I no longer have to show that

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i}{{n}\choose{i}}\frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{1}{n+1}(1+\frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{n})$

(as a second problem) because i managed to do it myself

Comment: When is this due?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: it is just recreational problem solving, it so happens that my double integration method with binomial coefficient formula didnt work :/, i just want to know how to do it to improve. if you want i can show you what i tried to do for both problems

Comment: I recommend rewriting the RHS of both lines in terms of the Harmonic numbers and studying known properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shall start with a couple of slightly easier sums
\begin{eqnarray*}
S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{n}{i} \frac{1}{i} \\
S_n^{+}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{n}{i} \frac{1}{i+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{1}{i}= \int_0^1 x^{i-1} dx \\
S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{n}{i} \int_0^1 x^{i-1} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Invert the sum & integral. Use the binomial expansion ... 
\begin{eqnarray*}
S_n=\int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} \binom{n}{i}  x^{i-1} dx =\int_0^1 \frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute $u=1-x$ & expand geometrically 
\begin{eqnarray*}
S_n=\int_0^1 \frac{1-u^n}{1-x} du =\int_0^1 (1+u+ \cdots +u^{n-1})du =1+\frac{1}{2}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{n}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do the second sum in a similar manner.
\begin{eqnarray*}
S_n^{+}=\int_0^1 (1-(1-x)^{n})dx=1-\frac{1}{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Partial fractions gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Your original sum is $S_n-S_n^+$ & the result follows.

Comment: thank you so much, i couldnt finish solving it because i didnt used partial fractions!